# While or for loop logic

Tags: sql, plsql

I am trying to write a logic for below requirements but I couldn't come up with solution.

1. For item I1 Cursor C1 will have fetch file_qty and table_qty where file_qty will be same for all the records.

2.depends on this data fetch insert should happen into table t2.

example:
for item I1 cursor C1 fetched 4 rows

```
file_qty=-12, table_qty=5
file_qty=-12, table_qty=6
file_qty=-12, table_qty=5
file_qty=-12, table_qty=4
```

then insert data into t2 until file_qty becomes zero. i.e

```
select sum(table_qty+file_qty) from dual;

for row1 : 5-12 =-7 = insert data into t2 with qty=5
for row2 : 6-7 = -1 = insert into t2 with qty=6
for row3 : 5-1 = 4 = insert into t2 with qty=1
for row4 no data should be inserted in t2 since file_qty has become zero. i.e 5+6+1 = 12 = file_qty
```

how can I implement this logic in plsql loop?

Comment: You can solve this problem in one simpel insert as select SQL with analytic function but you need to know ordering logic. You have to have column (like timestamp, value from sequence or something else) indicating order, historical appearence of records in the table.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of how you can write the procedure. Some parts are missing because you didn't described them in detail, but it should be easy to complete them (see comments):

```
DECLARE

    lc_file_qty NUMBER := -12;

BEGIN

    FOR c1 IN (
        SELECT table_qty
        FROM t1
        WHERE file_qty = lc_file_qty
        ORDER BY ??? -- Not clear if we need any ordering criteria?
    ) LOOP

        lc_file_qty := lc_file_qty + c1.table_qty;

        IF lc_file_qty >= 0 THEN EXIT; END IF; -- Break the loop

        INSERT INTO t2(???) VALUES (???); -- Insert into t2 table (must complete!)

    END LOOP;

    COMMIT;

END;
```